# Am I testing this right?

Tags: testing, unit-tests

Since I need to have 100% test coverage for the client, I'm writing integration and unit tests in my plugin. And I have a method in a class that is hooked to `admin_menu` hook, which adds submenu.

Apart from the thing that it's absolutely stupid to test this imo (if it doesn't work I won't see the submenu anyways), I wrote a test like this

```
<?php
/**
 * Class Users submenu test
 *
 * @package My_Plugin\Tests
 */

use My_Plugin\Users\Menu;

/**
 * Class that tests users menu functionality.
 */
class Add_Submenu_Integration_Tests extends WP_UnitTestCase {
  /**
   * Initial set up for the test
   */
  public function setUp() {
    parent::setUp();

    \wp_set_current_user( self::factory()->user->create( [
        'role' => 'administrator',
    ] ) );

    \update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://example.com' );
  }

  /**
   * Tear down after test ends
   */
  public function tearDown() {
    parent::tearDown();
  }

  public function test_user_import_submenu() {
    $user_import = new Menu();
    $user_import->add_users_submenu();

    $this->assertTrue( function_exists( 'add_submenu_page' ) );
  }

}
```

The class `Menu` has the method

```
public function add_user_import_submenu() : void {
  add_submenu_page(
    'users.php',
    esc_html__( 'Test submenu', 'my-plugin' ),
    esc_html__( 'Test submenu', 'my-plugin' ),
    'manage_options',
    'user-test',
    [ $this, 'submenu_view' ]
  );
}
```

Now, my test passes and the coverage is green, but I feel like I'm cheating xD

I tried to test using `global $submenu` but `$submenu` was empty.

Is this ok to do?